# kubectl does not work with multiple clusters config

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have `~/.kube/config` with following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://REDACTED.yl4.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: kubernetes-jenkins
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://REDACTED.sk1.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: kuberntes-dev
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes-dev
    user: aws-dev
  name: aws-dev
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes-jenkins
    user: aws-jenkins
  name: aws-jenkins
current-context: aws-dev
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: aws-dev
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - -i
      - EKS_DEV_CLUSTER
      command: heptio-authenticator-aws
      env: null
- name: aws-jenkins
  user:
     exec:
       apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
       args:
       - token
       - -i
       - EKS_JENKINS_CLUSTER
       command: heptio-authenticator-aws
       env: null
```

But when I'm trying to `kubectl cluster-info` I get:

```
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

As far as I understand something wrong in my kubeconfig, but I don't see what exactly. 
Also I tried to find any related issues, but with no luck.

Could you suggest me something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cluster name has a typo in it (`name: kuberntes-dev`) compared with the reference in the context (`cluster: kubernetes-dev`)

Answer (score 5):

You need to choose the context that you'd like to use. More informantion on how use multiple clusters with multiple users [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

Essentially, you can view your current context (for the current cluster configured)

```
$ kubectl config current-context
```

To view, all the clusters configured:

```
$ kubectl config get-clusters
```

And to choose your cluster:

```
$ kubectl config use-context <cluster-name>
```

There are options to set different users per cluster in case you have them defined in your `~/kube/config` file.

Comment: It should be `use-context` rather than `set-context`. If you check the docs, you see what the difference is ;)

Comment: Ahh, cool thx, fixed it! yea, set-context adds context details.

Comment: Thank you for information. I tried use use that, but issue was in typo.

Comment: Sure, no problem.